# NOT IN SELECT ... in IF statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get working an IF statement inside another IF in a trigger. The trigger has not syntax errors but it's not working. The IF code is the following:

```
.....
BEGIN
    IF (new.used <> old.used) THEN    
        IF (NEW.uid NOT IN (SELECT uid FROM subscriptions)) THEN
            UPDATE user_role SET user_role.rid=7 WHERE user_role.uid=new.uid;
        END IF;    
    END IF;
END$$
.....
```

I think the problem is in the second IF condition but I can't figure out what it is.
Any idea?? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a problem with case sensitivity.  Change `NEW.uid` to `new.uid`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: Oh man! Now it works! I thought there is not difference with caps, just because on MySQL I always use caps for the sql code!
Really thanks, as I said in another post I'm new with triggers and so I have some issues like this!!